# How to force ASP.NET forms authentication to use absolute URL for ReturnUrl parameter?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

When you use ASP.NET forms authentication, and you want to surf to a secure page like `securepage.aspx`, you would be redirected to this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/login.aspx?returnurl=securepage.aspx`
```

Is there a way to get the absolute URL in login page, like:

```
http://www.example.com/login.aspx?returnurl=http://www.example.com/securepage.aspx
```

I need this feature, because I'm working on a rather complicated SSO project, and I need to always work with absolute URLs.

Comment: [this link](http://blogs.freshlogicstudios.com/Posts/View.aspx?Id=cb739183-6a0b-46bc-9179-22aed8e60433) might help.

Comment: @Knvn, send your comment as an answer buddy. That was exactly what I wanted. :).

Comment: Too bad the content isn't posted, the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl=”true”
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.